# It enters the for only one time

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have an onChange function on my js code, this function has a foor loop that executed only once(the first time the function executed), I tried some things that made me make sure that the function running properly every time but the for loop only runs the first time although the length parameter i checked that it still the same value each time.

```
// loading the items to the menu
function loadmenu() {
    var selecteditem = $(".selected").text();

    alert(selecteditem);
    for (j == 0; j <= cats.length; j++) {

        if (selecteditem == cats[j]) {
            alert("eshta" + cats.length);
        }
    }

    $("#gallery").empty();
}
```

Comment: Where do you define `cats`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
for(j==0;j<=cats.length;j++){
```

to

```
for(var j=0; j<cats.length; j++){
```

In your present code, `j` is a global variable. The second time you get to the loop, `j` already is `cats.length+1` and as you use `j==0` you don't reset it.

If you want to iterate over all elements of the `cats` array, your halting condition should be `<`, not `<=`. Here your code will produce an error as you test `cats[cats.length]`.

Comment: Explaining the reason for why you should change it is generally what is required to make up a good answer

Comment: Side note : I suppose j is defined elsewhere, or the loop would *never* run.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `=` instead of `==` in your for loop. `==` is used for comparison. So in  your code `j` is not getting reset it is just used for comparison which it should not. So you need `=` for assigning the value for `j`.

```
for(var j=0;j<=cats.length;j++){
```